# Slow and Fast Video in AVPlayer then Save in Library

Tags: objective-c, iphone, video, ios7, avplayer

I have a video which I play by using avplayer. And then I have a feature where user can change rate of the movie to go faster or slower. Is there a way to save this fast or slowed down movie?

Comment: First, please help me how to create a feature where user can change rate to slower or faster?

Comment: avplayer has a rate property to change the speed. just be aware, you can only set it between 0.5 and 2.0 and even then only in steps of 0.25 (if I remember correctly). To save those avassetwriter and mutablecompositions might help you

Comment: @dimitri thnks yar..but i did it nd successfully completed using mutable composition.

Comment: Do you mind posting an example explaining how you did that? Thanks